# Regular expression Attribute that only allows alpha numeric characters

Tags: c#, regex, attributes

Using the expression below The error message shows when I enter "asdf" or "%#$%#$"

I only want to allow alpha numeric characters. Whats wrong with my syntax below?

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Only alpha numeric characters are allowed.")), Display(Name = "Program Codes"), RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]")]
    public string ProgramCode
    {
        get 
        {
            return _programCode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (OnPropertyChanging("ProgramCode", _programCode, value))
            {
                var oldValue = _programCode;
                _programCode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProgramCode", oldValue, value);
                OnProgramCodeChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You require the first character to be either a letter or a digit with `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]"`. It does not seem what you need. Try `@"^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"`. It will work [like this](https://regex101.com/r/yA6eJ3/1).

Comment: I don't want to require the first character to be anything. Just the entire string only alpha or numeric. What ever order. I'll give it a shot. thanks

Comment: *Just the entire string only alpha or numeric* sounds as if you want to allow `12345` or `asdf` like strings. However, you wrote something different in the question. I think you need  a regex to allow a string that should contain both at least 1 digit and at least 1 letter, and be composed from only letters and digits. Right?

Comment: yes 1234 or "aasdf" or "adsf1234". No" asdf-1234" or "adsf^&%" No special characters allowed. So when they do the error message should show. it can be all letters or all numbers or a mix. But no special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is nearly correct.  It will match any string in which the first character matches `[0-9A-Za-z]`.  Two things are missing; see the example and following explanation:

Script:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("asdf"));      // True
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(""));          // True
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("123abcABC")); // True
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("&%&"));       // False
```

Explanation:

- `^` denotes the beginning
- **`$` denotes the end**
- **`*` matches zero or more characters**

Adding the `*` and `$` in the way I've done above ensures that any and all matches will consist *entirely* of zero or more characters matching `[0-9A-Za-z]`.

So your example would look like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ("Only alpha numeric characters are allowed.")), Display(Name = "Program Codes"), RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")]
public string ProgramCode
{
    get 
    {
        return _programCode;
    }
    set
    {
        if (OnPropertyChanging("ProgramCode", _programCode, value))
        {
            var oldValue = _programCode;
            _programCode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProgramCode", oldValue, value);
            OnProgramCodeChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I put " var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");" above "public string ProgramCode" Also the using statement appears grey and not like my other using statements.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include what your code would look like now - you only need to add the `*` and the `$`.